React blank page on build
I've been learning React (kind of new to it) and I'm  working on a project and I did an npm create vite@latest. So far everything works fine when I do run dev. However when I do run build, then go to the dist folder and open the index.html file I get a blank page.
So I do an inspect page in FireFox and I get these errors -

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resources at file:///assets/index-J7cny882.js. (Reason: CORS request not http)
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resources at file:///assets/index-BAXwXR6k.css. (Reason: CORS request not http)

I'm bit puzzled by this. Don't know whats wrong or how to fix it. I did come across some things online that mentioned adding "homepage": "." to package.json. I did that but didn't help.
I appreciate the help.
Thanks.

Vite builds apps for use in a server environment. Use npm run preview to view the built application. See https://vite.dev/guide/cli#vite-preview

Did npm run preview , no longer a blank page but it now repeats it self.  It doesn't do this in run dev.

"it now repeats it self"... I have no idea what that means but it sounds like a completely different problem to the one described in your question

I see you have file:/// protocol, and the /assets is directly inside the root. First, I think you tried to open the html file directly, whereas vite emits a script tag with crossorigin which means the assets with "file" protocol will be blocked due to CORS policy. Second, the base is not set up properly. By adding "homepage": "." to package.json, I guess you meant that you are using an instruction from create-react-app, which does not use vite. For vite, one way is to add base: './', in vite.config.ts.

@qrsngky there is zero reason to change the Vite configuration unless OP actually has issues with their deployed app

This is what I meant by it repeats itself -
https://imghost.net/ib/9QGXvPly30InHyE_1732161655.png
It doesn't do that in run dev, but does in run preview.

In run build its just blank. The tutorials/learning videos  I used didn't mention server environment or CORS issues.
Perhaps I should of made it easier on myself and went with create-reat-app instead of Vite..

Nobody can help you with this without details. [Edit] your question (or preferably post a new one) containing a [mre]

Ok  got it working for the run preview but build is still blank but thats understandable.  I had to move the assets (pictures, audio.etc..) to the public folder and that allowed the preview to work just like the run dev.
Anyway thanks for the feedback.

You need to serve the page actually. If you are using the Vite create for React you can do the following to test your build.
// Build your project into the dist folder
npm run build 
// Preview your project using vite server
npm run preview

The preview command is already present on the package.json so you do not need to configure anything.
Keep in mind you should not use this for a production deploy. It only serves as a preview utility.
You can read the documentation here https://vite.dev/guide/cli#vite-preview


Serve the dist folder using a local HTTP server
The simplest solution is to use a local HTTP server to serve your built files. You can install one globally and use it:

Install a simple HTTP server:
npm install -g serve

Serve your dist folder:
serve dist

This will host your project on http://localhost:3000 (or another port it provides), and you can access your project without encountering CORS issues.

Adjust base in vite.config.js
When building with Vite, ensure the paths to your assets are relative or configured correctly. By default, Vite uses / as the base, which can cause issues if your project isn't served from a root path.

Modify the vite.config.js file to set a relative base:
javascript


import { defineConfig } from 'vite'

export default defineConfig({
  base: './', // Ensures relative paths for assets
})



Then rebuild your project:
npm run build

Now, the paths in the generated index.html file will be relative, and you can open it directly in the browser without needing a local server.

Avoid opening directly with file:///
Browsers enforce stricter security policies for files opened with file:///. Using a local HTTP server (as shown in step 1) avoids these restrictions.


Vite already comes with the preview option. There's no need to install a separate web server or change configuration

[from the end of your part 2] "you can open it directly in the browser without needing a local server" - nope, won't work. And it contradicts the work in part 1 and 3.
